# How to convert this combination sum algorithm from java to javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Here is the [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum) question, for combination sum problem.

One answer [code](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/discuss/16509/Iterative-Java-DP-solution) is here in java. (or see follow)

```
public class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] cands, int t) {
        Arrays.sort(cands); // sort candidates to try them in asc order
        List<List<List<Integer>>> dp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++) { // run through all targets from 1 to t
            List<List<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList(); // combs for curr i
            // run through all candidates <= i
            for (int j = 0; j < cands.length && cands[j] <= i; j++) {
                // special case when curr target is equal to curr candidate
                if (i == cands[j]) newList.add(Arrays.asList(cands[j]));
                // if current candidate is less than the target use prev results
                else for (List<Integer> l : dp.get(i-cands[j]-1)) {
                    if (cands[j] <= l.get(0)) {
                        List cl = new ArrayList<>();
                        cl.add(cands[j]); cl.addAll(l);
                        newList.add(cl);
                    }
                }
            }
            dp.add(newList);
        }
        return dp.get(t-1);
    }
}
```

I need to convert it in javascript.

Here is my attempt.

```
function sortFunc(a, b) {
    return a-b;
}

function combinationSum(cands, t) {
    cands.sort(sortFunc);

    let dp = []; //[[[]]];

    for (let i = 1; i <= t; i++) {

        console.log('-- i --');
        console.log(i);

        let newList = []; // [[]];

        for (let j = 0; j < cands.length && cands[j] <= i; j++)
        {
            console.log('-- j --');
            console.log(j);

            if (i === cands[j]) {

                console.log('-- push --');
                console.log(i);

                newList.push([cands[j]]);
            }
            else {
                // list of int
                let myListList = dp[i-cands[j]-1];

                for(let k=0; k<myListList.length; k++) {
                    let myList = myListList;

                    if(cands[j] <= myList[0]) {
                        myListList.unshift([cands[j]]);
                        newList.push(myListList);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        dp.push(newList);
    }

    return dp[t-1];
}

let arr = [2, 3, 5];
let t = 15;
let out = combinationSum(arr, t);
console.log(out);
```

I have some understanding of the code, but not a lot. Currently, my javascript is in infinite loop.

Does anyone know why?
Or if you have a better solution for "combination sum"?

Comment: You should add the input and expected output to the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went off the rails a bit in the last for loop and kept adding to `myNewList` inside the loop based on it's length so the loop never ended.

Here's a version that sticks pretty close to the original:

```js
function sortFunc(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

function combinationSum(cands, t) {
  cands.sort(sortFunc);

  let dp = []; //[[[]]];

  for (let i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
    let newList = []; // [[]];

    for (let j = 0; j < cands.length && cands[j] <= i; j++) {
      if (i === cands[j]) {
        newList.push([cands[j]]);
      } else {
        for (l of dp[i - cands[j] - 1]) {  // for of is similar to `for (List<Integer> l : dp.get(i-cands[j]-1))`
          if (cands[j] <= l[0]) {
            let cl = [cands[j], ...l]     // use spread ...l to get ArrayList.addall() behavior
            newList.push(cl)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    dp.push(newList);
  }

  return dp[t - 1];
}

let arr = [2, 3, 5, 4];
let t = 7;
let out = combinationSum(arr, t);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: not sure that is the place to ask. Extra requirement: allow the program to offer a solution through rounding up where there is not an exact combination that can be applied to reach the input. e.g. input [4, 5], then we have target = 7. I assume the [5] is picked. as it is close to 7. If I want to modify the program above, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
let myList = myListList;
```

You create a reference to `myListList` rather than a copy so that when you start manipulating the `myListList` array you end up in an endless loop.

to fix it, copy the myListList array like this

```
let myList = myListList.splice();
```